# Custom marker icon google map android

Tags: java, android

Can we custom marker icon google map?
I dont want just simply change the icon bitmap (I know how to do it)
I want to change the icon in the way like I have a xml layout (with have one imageview and a textview) and I want to inflate this xml (like custom info window). But I want to make it marker icon, so I can set image and text by coding
Note that I dont want a info window, I want it to be a marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `layour` and convert that layout into Drawable and you can add that drawable into icon of your marker.

You can create your layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    "/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below method will give your the Bitmap from a layout,

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromLayout(int layout) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());

    view.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
        drawable.draw(canvas);

    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

You can add the Bitmap in map marker icon like this,

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitMapFromLayout([your layout id]))));
```

Comment: If i do it in that way, I cant set text and image programmatically

Comment: Yes, you can set any view in your layout not only text or image.

Comment: Add your crash log.

Comment: I got crash width and height must be > 0 while create bitmap. something wrong happened when trying to inflate layout

Comment: I added **view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    view.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());** this piece of code.

Comment: Another question. How doyou learn how to write that code? and  I have to load image from server to that ImageView. I use Glide library and this seems that the icon shows up before Glide successfully load the image. So the imageview is blank

Comment: I successfully load the image by writing callback. Thank you